# PHP PDO - import sql files ignoring duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, pdo

I've wrote a script which is responsible for importing sql files into database. Here is how it looks like:

```
<?php

$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = '';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_database = '';

try
   {
     $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$mysql_database.';host='.$mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);
     $sql = implode(array_map(function ($v) {
        return file_get_contents($v);
        }, glob(__DIR__ . "/*.sql")));

     $qr = $db->exec($sql); 
     echo "Import action - 100% successfull";
   }
   catch (PDOException $e) 
   {
     echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<BR />
```

It works. But I would like to add one more function - avoid inserting duplicates. Currently each time when I will run the script, i will import files and at the end - creating bunch of duplicates. How to make it work properly? or at least - overriding everything in the Database (but i would like to avoid such solution..)

Comment: What kind of duplicates are you talking about? Are there files with the same name? Or do separate files contain the same INPUT statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create [unique index or primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on the fields that need to be unique.
2. Optional - if you want to execute more than one insert in  a transaction: Make sure that the [sql mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) for your session is not set to strict. If it is set to strict, then change it to non-strict.
3. Execute the inserts

3.b Optional: If you chose not to touch the sql mode, but still would like to execute more than 1 insert per transaction, then change the inserts into insert ignore by injecting the ignore keyword after insert from the php code.

4. Optional: if you had to change the sql mode in step 2, then set the sql mode back to what it was.

There are some drawbacks if you use insert ignore or disable strict sql mode (quote from sql modes link):

> If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings (see Section 13.7.5.40, “SHOW WARNINGS Syntax”). In strict mode, you can produce this behavior by using INSERT IGNORE or UPDATE IGNORE.

Comment: i have primary keys in all tables to which I want to insert data via mentioned files. yet still, my code duplicate some of the rows. Can you help me somehow with the script itself?

Comment: If you have a primary key defined, then you cannot have duplicate rows,  at least the pk must be different. So, you need to be a lot more specific about what you mean by a duplicate record.

Comment: ok - let's say We have a table called VISITORS with columns (id, name, surname, phone, sales). My primary key is id. I have a row: #1 | John | Doyle | 4433222 | 320). This record exists in the offline DB from which I create sql file, and also exist in the online DB (destination one). When I use my script, this record will be added as e.g. #201 | John | Doyle | 4433222 | 320. And i want to avoid such situation - i want insert only those rows which are still not available in destination DB.

Comment: Then you need to create a unique index on the combination of fields that you do not want to be duplicate. The other option is to import the data into an empty staging table and use insert select with a left join to move the data into the production table that does not exsist there.

Comment: create unique index where? in script or table or where?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you mean that there a bunch of the same statements in there. If it are all simple statements, and there is no string value in there with `;`, then you could try by using:

```
$sql = implode(';', array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(';', $sql))));
```

But then again, there are a lot of corner cases

- Different statements can insert the same stuff
- There is a string value with a `;` *(this does not necessarily have to be a problem)*
- Usage of a different delimiter character in the sql
- If there are Stored Procedures / Triggers / Functions in the SQL file
- ...

But it is a start, and perhaps it will suffice for your use-case

Comment: Im uploading few Times per Day several sql files. Each of them includes insert Statements to specific database tables. What i would like to avoid is situation when Through file import im duplicating some values. Reason why is that in those files are generated by backup script so they include all db data. I want to import only such data which doesnt exist in destination db

Comment: @JuliaGalden Are there no primary/unique keys on the tables?

Comment: everything (in all files) looks like that: INSERT INTO SALES(DATA, WIZ_ID, CUST_ID, ANI_ID, DOCTOR_ID, TYP_WIZ, DOC_TYPE_ID, AMOUNT, DBS-DATE, DBS-HOUR) VALUES ('2015-07-27', 10000012, '011500010', '011500012', 3431, 1, 'PARAGON', 100.0000, '2015-07-27', '10:25:56');